# How do I program AES-40 Encryption in Java?

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, aes

For my science fair project, I will be studying AES encryption and analyzing results from different sized keys for AES Encryption. For example, I would want to study about 40-bit sized keys and observe how long it takes to break them. I know how AES-128 works (16-byte key, creates a matrix of bits and shifts them accordingly), however, I was wondering how I would be able to code AES using 40 bits instead of 128 bits?

Note: This is for educational purposes only, (not actually going to use to secure anything), and the language preferably is Java, however other languages are also welcome.

Comment: AES is *not* simple to program.  For a simpler example build your own [Feistel cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feistel_cipher) with whatever block size you want: 40 bits in your case.  Both 32 bit and 64 bit are easy since those are standard sizes in Java.  That would give you three examples to compare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well [AES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard#High-level_description_of_the_algorithm) is only defined for key sizes 128, 192 and 256.  So AES-40 is not a thing.

Now I suppose that you could limit the key size to 40 bits by taking one of the recognized AES variants and passing a 40 bit keys with zeros.  But don't call this AES, because it isn't real AES.

The Wikipedia has a high-level description of the AES algorithm(s) and links to other resources.

Answer (score 1):

There is a definition of S-AES or Simple AES out there for educational purposes, but it has a key & block size of 16 bits and works with nibbles as words.

You can find a reference e.g. [here](https://www.rose-hulman.edu/~holden/Preprints/s-aes.pdf). Happy programming.